# Change SharpPcap ICaptureDevice properties inside my ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms

In order to receivedall machine adapters I am using:

```
CaptureDeviceList adapters = CaptureDeviceList.Instance;
```

This returns list of all the available adapters.

This is my combobox adapter SelectedIndexChanged method:

```
private void cbAdapter_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cmb = sender as ComboBox;
    ICaptureDevice selectedAdapter = cmb.SelectedItem as ICaptureDevice;
    adapter = cbAdapter.SelectedIndex;
    ICaptureDevice selectedNic = cbAdapter.SelectedItem as ICaptureDevice;
}
```

After this command the combobox show my interface name inside but the name is with additional characters for example: `interface: Name: rpcap://\Device\NPF_{53418AFD-2965-4F99-BCAA-ECFB8B993B7B}`

My question: is it possible to edit this adapter id to something like `{53418AFD-2965-4F99-BCAA-ECFB8B993B7B}` or maybe even using other adapter properties like the name instead of the id?